# Evaluate $\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2-2xy-y^2}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I would like to compute the following,
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2-2xy-y^2}\ dx\,dy
$$
It is obvious that we can rewrite the integral above to,
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(x+y)^2}\ dx\,dy
$$
so we are ending up with something looking like a gaussian integral. I think that a smart substitution would help but all I tried ended up to be something I am not able to compute...

I really would appreciate any hint.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do a rotation of $x,y$ plane by 45 degrees.

Comment: To follow up: let $u = x + y$, $v = x - y$; then $|duv/dxy| = 2$, and the rest is just mechanical. The limits on $u$ and $v$ are still $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Do you suppose that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$? or you want to prove it?

Comment: @Jika No I know that, just want to compute the above one with help of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{x + y}^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd x:\
     {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{x + y}^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd x}
> \\[5mm] = &\
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}\expo{-y^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
> =\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-y^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
> \right\vert_{y\ >\ x}
> \\[3mm]&=\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-y^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\,\dd x\,\dd y
> \right\vert_{x\ <\ y}
> =
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-y^{2}}\int_{0}^{y}\,\dd x\,\dd y
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}y\expo{-y^{2}}\,\dd y
> \\[5mm] = &\
> \left.-\,\half\,\expo{-y^{2}}\right\vert_{0}^{\infty} =
> \color{#66f}{\Large\half}
> \end{align}

Comment: May I ask how you derived the third integral? I dont see how to obtain $\int_0^y$...

Comment: @Thorben In the second, the $\large y$-integration satisfies $\large y>x$ which is equivalent to $\large x<y$. It's clear from $\large \int_{x}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-y^{2}} =\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-y^{2}}\right\vert_{y > x}$.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Thorben I add a few steps more to illustrate my previous comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

> **[Theorem](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParametricIntro.aspx) :** $$ \iint_A f(x,y)\ dx\,dy=\iint_B g(u,v) |J|\ du\,dv, $$
>   where $J$ is [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

Now, using parametric equations $u=x+y$ and $v=x$ then its Jacobian is $-1$. The corresponding regions are $0<x<\infty\;\Rightarrow\;0<v<\infty$ and $0<y<\infty\;\Rightarrow\;0<u-v<\infty$. Hence
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{\large-(x+y)^2}\ dx\,dy&=\int_{v=0}^\infty\int_{u=v}^\infty e^{\large-u^2}\ du\,dv\\
&=\int_{u=0}^\infty\int_{v=0}^u e^{\large-u^2}\ dv\,du\\
&=\int_{u=0}^\infty u\ e^{\large-u^2}\ du\qquad;\qquad\text{let}\ t=u^2\;\Rightarrow\;dt=2u\ du\\
&=\frac12\int_{t=0}^\infty \ e^{\large-t}\ dt\\
&=\large\color{blue}{\frac12}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Switch to polar coordinates i.e $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$ and $dx\,dy=r\,dr\,d\theta$ to obtain:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\infty} re^{-r^2(1+\sin(2\theta))}dr\,d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{2(1+\sin(2\theta))}\,d\theta$$
Write $\sin(2\theta)=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$ to get:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{2(1+\sin(2\theta))}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sec^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta+2\tan\theta}\,d\theta$$
Use the substitution $\tan\theta=t \Rightarrow \sec^2\theta\,d\theta=dt$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sec^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta+2\tan\theta}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(1+t)^2}=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{2}}$$